# How to call another function to an executing thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, oop, streamlit

```
import threading
import time
 
class Test():
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.stop_threads = False
    
    def run(self):
        
        while True:
            print('thread running')
            time.sleep(5)
            
            if self.stop_threads:
                break
            
    def store(self):  
        
        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.run())
        self.t1.start()


    def stop(self):    
        self.stop_threads = True
        self.t1.join()
        print('thread killed')
```

When user clicks on the "Run" button, the store() function will execute. There is another button "Stop" which when clicked, the stop() function executes.

GUI:

```
from test2 import *
import streamlit as st

obj=Test()

if st.button("Run"):
    obj.store()


if st.button("Stop"):
    obj.stop()
```

But since there is an infinite loop, I am unable to click the "Stop" button.

How can I implement the stop button?

Comment: Did you mean: `self.t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.run)`?

Comment: yes i meant self.run

Comment: I reverted your edit. Please do not go back and fix the problem that you are asking about when somebody shows you what you did wrong. These questions and answers are archived for the benefit of other people who may be seeking answers to similar problems. They won't be able to understand your question if the code example does not still contain the defect that caused you to ask.

Comment: For benefit of those other readers: The problem is that, `target=self.run()` _calls_ the `run()` function to get a target for the new thread, but since the `run()` function never returns, the new thread never is created—the calling thread does the work. And, since `run()` never returns, that means `store()` never returns to the GUI framework's main event loop, and the application will be unable to respond to the mouse. The fix is to write `target=self.run` (i.e., to provide a reference to the run function itself as the target instead of calling the run function.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow sorry about that but even with editing the code the thread is not terminating

Comment: @MyronDsilva, If changing `self.run()` to `self.run` did not fix the problem, then I've got to ask, is that the entire program? If it is, then I've got to wonder whether your are using streamlit correctly. (I don't know streamlit, so I can't help there.) Maybe get a clean start, and re-ask the question.